# How to use Webshere MQ Server via ActiveMQ server and what to bear in mind?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, ibm-mq

We have a requirment to connect to a JMS queue provided by an externally controlled IBM Websphere MQ server. Now, the easiest way to do it would be to include the Websphere MQ client into our application and just use the queue.

But IBM was so far not able to tell me about possible licensing costs of this setup. I saw forum posts and hints on IBM download pages that using the client is free of charge, but I do not know for sure. Maybe it's even the case, that the owner of the MQ server is allowed to provide us the client jar to use it for connecting to them, but again, I don't know for sure.

So I am evaluating the possibility to setup my own open source JMS server, for example an Apache ActiveMQ, and then bridge over to the Websphere MQ. For this, 2 questions rise up for me:

1. Technical solution: How would that be done exactly? I read a bit about bridging between JMS providers and something about the Apache Camel project, but have so far no exact idea how much work this will be and what needs exactly to be done.
2. Impacts: What should I bear in mind when implementing such a scenario? Do I still have to include the MQ client and such would not benefit over a direct connect? Are there any negative impacts compared to a direct connect that I must consider?

---

Update: Our application is a Java EE 6 application running on a JBosss 7.1. <del>Concerning the MQ server version I have no information yet.</del>

---

2nd Update: The MQ server version is 6.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client to MQ is available for you to use; there's a license agreement to accept not a charge. 
There are several options for how these client libraries could get to you practically.

You mention JMS is being used - within what container/environment is this? JavaSE/JavaEE/OSGi or something else.

- JavaSE or the 'something else' would the JMS Client JARs.
- JavaEE would need the IBM MQ Resource Adapter
- OSGi would need the OSGi Bundles

In earlier versions of MQ there was the 'extended transnational client' that had a charge associated with it (pretty much the same as a full server) but that is no more.

As this is for JBOSS 7.1 - the solution would be to follow this link 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21633761

.. and download the IBM MQ Resource Adapter directly from the instructions there... 7.5.0.4 has also been released this last week. Please consider this as downloading the MQCxxx support pac will give you too much. This download does have the license agreement to accept but it's the same as the one has been highlighted elsewhere.  It does mention Liberty but it's the same RA that is supported for within JBOSS.

For information on configuring the RA inside JBOSS please look at

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031820_.htm

The version of the RA or JMS client code is not tightly coupled with the server version. Client or bindings.

You won't have any support apart from via the web; unless you get the company running the externally controlled server to raise it.

Edit: have added download links

Comment: You are right, haven't mentioned that, I updated my answer. Still, same applies as for Erik's answer - I am in need of some "official" statement in order to be sure for the proposal on the fact of licensing costs.

Comment: Added another update: The MQ version is not the latest one - does this affect your solution or the extended client you mentioned?

Comment: Not at all; download the 7.5 version of the Resource Adapter via the linked I mentioned. This is able to connect to all in-service QueueManagers (7.0, 7.1, 7.5, 8.0). MQ v6 is now out-of-support (though the 7.5 RA could still connect if needed).

Don't worry about the extended client as of a 7.5 level this function is rolled into the main code line - i.e. it's a standard feature.

Answer (score 2):

Pasting from this [page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24032744)

Category 3 WebSphere MQ SupportPacs are supplied under the standard terms and conditions provided by the International Program License Agreement (IPLA) and thus, carry program defect service for WebSphere MQ customers. Please read the IPLA and LI files that accompany the SupportPac, to ensure you understand the conditions under which the SupportPac is provided.

If you encounter what you believe to be a defect with the SupportPac, and you have a current license for a WebSphere MQ server product, you may request Program Services by reporting the problem via the same defect reporting channel you employ for the WebSphere MQ server product(s) on which you are using the SupportPac. **No proof of entitlement is required to use this SupportPac.**

Service is available for the v7.5 version of this SupportPac for as long as the WebSphere MQ V7.5 server product is supported by service. Refer to the WebSphere product lifecycle pages for the relevant service information. It is only supported with MQ platforms which are themselves supported.

I am thinking text in bold indicates MQ Client is free.

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere MQ Client has no licensing fees.  The only fees (and I think they did away with this one) would have been for the XA client.  The client download should come with Client for JMS, which is not the same as Client for Java (native IBM API in java).  When you install the client, just check to ensure you have /java/   which will contain all of the dependent jars for connecting to IBM MQ.

1. I would highly suggest using Apache Camel as your bridge vs creatng your own.  You can then choose to run the camel route inside of the ActiveMQ JVM or other supported container.  Most of the work will be learning how to do it the first time. Once you have it set up you will realize the time savings and power of Apache Camel.
2. No matter what you need MQ Client. MQ Server includes MQ Client, so if all this  is on the same host you have nothing else to install.  If by direct connect you mean bindings mode vs client mode, then yes, bindings mode is always the most efficient. And on the flip side, if you run your route in your broker you can take advantage of the VM transport.

The main considerations you need to think about for messages bridging between ActiveMQ and WebSphere MQ are really typical messaging questions. For example, Do you need the message to survive an outtage? If so, then consider using local transactions with your routes.

Comment: I heard the very same about MQ Client beeing free of charge, but do you have an official source for that? But when trying to find this on the IBM website (e.g. [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg27007198#3), they speak about "available at no charge to all licensed users of the WebSphere MQ", which I am not.

Comment: What Shashi posted in his answer is what I would have posted as well.  IBM keeps is pay to use stuff pretty well locked down.  Only specific members of your organization have download rights to any of the "not-free" stuff.  But I have to ask, who owns the WMQ server that you'd be bridging to/from?  There is no point in having MQ client if no one is paying for MQ Server for that client to connect to, which is what IBM really cares about.

Comment: The server is owned by another company and surely be licensed. They provide information to several others by MQ queues (or maybe topics), so we are one of their clients using it.

Answer (score 1):

Bridging an ActiveMQ broker with a WebSphere MQ queue manager requires the same client libraries as a direct connection.

You are correct that you can pretty easy setup such a bridge using [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/jms), that comes bundled with ActiveMQ.

One possible benefit from having a local broker as a buffer might be that your application can rely on a broker that is up and controlled by you. The remote/external controlled WebSphere MQ might be taken down for maint. by external parties or the network might be shaky. Of course, your application can handle such things using logic and rescheduled transmissions but it's far easier to set up a Camel route in ActiveMQ to do that and focus your logic in the application to do business logic.